# R: How to update R when I get an error message with installR

Tags: r, installr

Not sure how I'm supposed to update R to 3.4.4 when I get this error:

> Error: (converted from warning) package 'installr' was built under R version 3.4.4

Any ideas?

Comment: check `options("warning")` and set `options(warning=0)`. If all else fails, just do it manually - the only hassle is reinstalling packages, and to be honest it is not a huge deal. You can always save `rownames(installed.packages))` to a text file and use that to reinstall them.

Comment: OK, thanks, but I'd really like to know why this is happening to me.  Everytime I re-start R do I have to install all the packages I need all over again because that seems to be what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with `options(error=recover)`? That should help you hunt for where `installr` is setting `warning` to a higher level.